# Error while resizing image

Tags: python, opencv

Im using the following code to crop the face and save it.

```
 while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.1,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(30, 30),
            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        )

        # Draw a rectangle around the faces
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x - 60, y - 60), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            imgCrop = frame[y - 60:y + h, x - 60:x + w]

            imgCrop = cv2.resize(imgCrop, (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

            cv2.imwrite("check.jpg", imgCrop)
```

Im getting the following error while doing so.

> imgCrop = cv2.resize(imgCrop, (224, 224),
>   interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC) cv2.error:
>   /Users/jenkins/miniconda/1/x64/conda-bld/conda_1486587097465/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3229: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0 in function resize

How can I be able to sort this out?

Update:

```
 if ret:
        # Draw a rectangle around the faces
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x - 60, y - 60), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            imgCrop = frame[y - 60:y + h, x - 60:x + w]

            imgCrop = cv2.resize(imgCrop, (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

            cv2.imwrite("check.jpg", imgCrop)
```

Comment: You're resizing an empty image

Comment: You can sort this out by doing some debugging. What did you do so far to investigate this problem? In the error message you can clearly see the statement which causes this. There's also a hint in the error, that some sort of area failed to be greater than 0. The only input we give it that could possibly have an area is the input image. Did you inspect the value of `imgCrop` before you pass it to `resize`? Did you inspect anything else in order to drill in and find the root cause?

Comment: Additionally (as I've already mentioned in another of your questions), you need to test the results of functions that can fail, before you start using them, (i.e. merrily pass as parameters to other functions). Specifically in this case, `video_capture.read()` can fail... you even capture `ret`, but you never test it. Why?

Comment: i have tried checking with ret. see the updated code plz

Comment: Try to display the image using ```cv2.imshow("Cropped Image",imgCrop)``` before resizing. If it displays fine then 
```cv2.resize(imgCrop, (224, 224), 0,0,interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)```

Comment: how do I check if it is displaying properly?